# Agar.io-like cell physics

Tags: java, graphics, game-physics, slick2d

I wanted to make a circle that has a ripple-effect on the edges, kind of like in the game [agar.io](http://agar.io/). I am kind of lost on how to implement it. Obviously I can't just g.fillOval() because that would draw a solid circle with no movement on the edges.

I'm not asking anyone to write any code for me (but if you really want to, I don't mind :D), but if you could point me in the right direction with some methods I should use. I am using Slick-2D library for java, if that helps.

I also tried analyzing the javascript source from the [agar.io](http://agar.io/) website to try to understand how they implemented it in javascript, but I was unsuccessful because the code was obfuscated; all the methods and variables were just single letters.

The only way I can imagine doing this currently is to have each circle be composed of a number of points, and let each point have it's own physics, and it can be affected by other points. If anyone who has insight into this problem, I would greatly appreciate some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this with Slick2D. It is quite high level and gives a lot built-in classes. What you want to do is really specific. As Slick development has stopped you will not get new features. You should probably look at lwjgl which is the base of Slick. It is more low-level but can be more precise with the form you need.

You can look at [this project](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/2D-Pixel-Perfect-Shadows) to have some drawing cool stuff. And for another example of manipulating circle you have [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957727/lwjgl-circle-program-creates-an-oval-like-shape)